# Fatal error: Class RecursiveDirectoryIterator not found

Tags: php, copy

I have two question,
 first I have this error : Fatal error: Class 'ClicShopping\Sites\ClicShoppingAdmin\RecursiveDirectoryIterator' not found in
I don't know exactly why.

Do you need to use namespace and how to write the function ?

```
use \RecursiveDirectoryIterator
```

My second question is : how the exclude files like license or  readme.txt in the copy.

Thanks

```
    class toto {

        public static function smartCopy($source, $dest) {
  @mkdir($dest, 0755);
  foreach (


    $iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
      new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source, \RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
      \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
    ) as $item
  ) {
    if ($item->isDir()) {
      mkdir($dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
    } else {

      if ($item != 'README.md' && $item != 'LICENSE') {
        copy($item, $dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

and

```
public function getInstallModuleFixe($file) {

      $zip_file = DIR_FS_CATALOG . 'plugin_download/' . $file .'.zip';
      $archive = new \PclZip($zip_file);

      $list = $archive->listContent();
      if ($list == 0) {
        die("Error : ".$archive->errorInfo(true));
      }


      $extract = $archive->extract(PCLZIP_OPT_EXTRACT_DIR_RESTRICTION, DIR_FS_CATALOG . 'plugin_download',
                                   PCLZIP_OPT_PATH, DIR_FS_CATALOG . 'plugin_download'
      );


      if (is_dir(DIR_FS_CATALOG . 'plugin_download/'. $file.'-master')) {
        static::smartCopy(DIR_FS_CATALOG . 'plugin_download/'. $file.'-master' , DIR_FS_CATALOG . 'plugin_download/test/');
      } else {
        echo 'no copy';
        die();
      }
}
```

Comment: `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` uses the global namespace, so doing an `use` statement is absolutely unnecessary. Prepend a backslash before the classname for the full qualified global namespace instead (`new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator`). Do the same thing with class constants `\RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS`.

Comment: If your classes are namespaced, then you either have to specify the correct namespace in the `use` statements, or use the fully qualified name in-line. the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` class is a standard PHP object, and resides in the global namespace: `\RecursiveDirectoryIterator`, not `/RecursiveDirectoryIterator`. The use-statement is incorrect, and so wherever you're using the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` name without the leading backslash, your autoloader is kicking in (and failing)

Comment: @CharlotteDunois: Global namespaced classes/interfaces _do_ need either the leading backslash, or a use statement to include them if your code is fully namespaced

Comment: I changed (see code) the class Toto (also the namespace) and I have always now this error Fatal error: Call to undefined function ....\RecursiveIteratorIterator()

Comment: i Found solution,  the code is above. thank you.